# Second Select Query in function not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to execute 2 Select queries, one right after the other. The first query is contained in a function. From within this function another function is called containing the sql statement. 
At first I tried to add both sql statements into the same function. That did not work either. The first query executes correctly, but the second query does not.
If I execute the queries separately, they work just fine.

The first query, takes the id passed from a form and returns the information for a member. This involves several tables. The member information is contained in one table. The city, state, and county are each in their own table.
Each member can have up to two categories attached. I created an additional SQL select statement to retrieve that information, again, using the member id to isolate the information.

```
function editmember()
     global $db;
     $sql = "SELECT m.Id, m.Lname, m.Fname, m.Company, m.Street, m.Zip, m.Phone1, m.Phone2, m.Email, m.Web, m.Active, cy.Name, s.Abbr, co.Name
     FROM tbl_Members AS m
     JOIN tbl_City AS cy
     ON m.City=cy.Id
     JOIN tbl_State AS s
     ON m.State=s.Id
     JOIN tbl_County AS co
     ON m.County=co.Id
     WHERE mId=$id";

     $sqlRes = $db->prepare($sql);

     if($sqlRes->execute()) {
        $sqlRes-> bind_result($id, $lname, $fname, $comp, $street, $zip, $phonea,$phoneb, $email, $web, $status, $city, $state, $county); 
        while($sqlRes->fetch()) {
           $ems .= "$id, $lname, $fname, $comp, $street, $zip, $phonea, $phoneb, $email, $web, $status, $city, $state, $county"; 
           $ems .= getcat($id); 
        }
     }


     return $ems;   
}
```

This is the second function

```
function getcatsql($id)
{
     global $db;
     $sql = "SELECT mtgId, mtgMemId, mtgGId FROM tbl_mem_to_group WHERE    mtgMemId=$id";
     $sqlRes = $db->prepare($sql);
     if($sqlRes->execute()) {
        $sqlRes-> bind_result($mtgid, $memid, $catid);
        while($sqlRes->fetch()) {
           $ems = "$mtgid, $memid,$catid";
        }
     }

     return $ems;
}
```

Unfortunately I have tried and failed to find an answer online. I truly hope, someone can point me into the right direction. 
I also tried to be detailed in my description. If not, please let me know and I will provide further details. As of now, I truly do not know how to proceed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am sorry, I am pretty new here. I used the suggested tags. Should not be sql-server. PDO

Comment: Okay, tags updated. Try checking for errors, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php. Also I try to keep all variables out of my queries. I use placeholders, `?` and pass the values in the execute. Example 3, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: You need to use an `@` before the user's name to tag them.

Comment: @piotm, I was actually wondering, if i could do that. However, the first query is to return 1 result only, whereas the second query should return multiple.

Comment: Check var_dump($ems)

Comment: I assumed a join would be possible because In the second function you are overwriting $ems for every fetched row, without doing anything with it. So only the last one will be returned and so I thought only one was supposed to be fetched. Other than that a hint should be in the error messages.

Comment: @piotm I receive the following on the second function: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object. It appears that error points to a problem in the SQL statement. Unfortunately I am not seeing it. I rewrote it several time as well, i case I was making an error in typing.

Comment: @chris85 I looked up  the links you posted and tried out the suggestions but it still does not work.

Comment: Check that link about errors chris85 mentioned. See what $db->errorInfo() or $sqlRes->errorInfo() hold after using their methods.

Comment: Try running the query on your DB, are there rows being returned?

Comment: PDO::errorInfo(): 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo()

Comment: @chris85 If I run query no 2 without query no 1, it executes perfectly. Once I bring the first query into the equation, the second query fizzles out. The first one executes. I receive error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object.

Comment: You did `print_r($sqlRes->errorInfo());` and it gave you `PDO::errorInfo(): Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo()`?

Comment: I did print_r($db->errorInfo());

Comment: @chris85 I changed it to $sqlRes with the same results.

Comment: It sounds like `mysqli` is being used with `pdo` which won't work.

Comment: That is not good. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think mysqli and PDO are compatible as shown in the error you provided.  So what I do for my database connection is:

```
function dbConnect()
{

    global $dbh;

    $dsn = DB_HOST;
    $user = DB_USER;
    $password = DB_PASS;


    try 
    {           
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        //echo("<p>Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>");
    }


    return $dbh;
}
```

And then I execute the queries like:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM accessControl WHERE ip = ? AND subnet = ?");             
$stmt->bindParam(1, $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $subnet, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();
```

And then disconnect:

```
function dbDisconnect()
{
    global $dbh;
    $dbh = null;
    return $dbh;
}
```

There's a lot about PDO here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php  but I don't think mysqli is the correct thing here :)

Also you could do a JOIN and execute something similar to:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN questions ON users.questionID = questions.questionID WHERE email = ?");
```

That way you don't have to iterate through each entry for the second table: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the tips.
I solved the problem by the following:

First of all I changed my connection string.

```
function doDB()
{
$db= new PDO('mysql:host=hoststring;dbname=dbname', 'username', 'password');
}
```

Then I changed the first function from an prepared statement to this

```
function memberedit()
{
 $sql = "SELECT m.Id, m.Lname, m.Fname, m.Company, m.Street, m.Zip, m.Phone1, m.Phone2, m.Email, m.Web, m.Active, cy.Name, s.Abbr, co.Name
                        FROM tbl_Members AS m
                        JOIN tbl_City AS cy
                        ON m.City=cy.Id
                        JOIN tbl_State AS s
                        ON m.State=s.Id
                        JOIN tbl_County AS co
                        ON m.County=co.Id
                        WHERE m.Id=$id";

        foreach ($db->query($sql) AS $row) {
            $memid = $row['Id'];
            $lname = $row['Lname'];
            $fname = $row['Fname']; 
            $comp = $row['Company'];
            $street = $row['Street'];
            $zip = $row['Zip'];
            $phonea = $row['Phone1'];
            $phoneb = $row['Phone2'];
            $email = $row['Email'];
            $web = $row['Web'];
            $status = $row['Active']; 
            $city = $row['Name'];
            $state = $row['Abbr'];
            $county = $row['Name'];
        $ems .= "$id, $lname, $fname, $comp, $street, $zip, $phonea, $phoneb, $email, $web, $status, $city, $state, $county"; 
        $ems .= getcat($id);
        }

        return $ems;    
}
```

Continued to do the same to the second statement

```
function getcat($id)
{
    global $db; 

    $sql = "SELECT mtgId, mtgMemId, mtgGId FROM tbl_mem_to_group WHERE mtgMemId=$id";
            foreach ($db->query($sql) AS $row) {
            $mtgid = $row['mtgId'];
            $memid = $row['mtgMemId'];
            $catid = $row['mtgGId'];
$ems .= "<p>$mtgid, $memid, $catid</p>";
            }

    return $ems;
}
```

Now both queries return the results I needed. 
Thank you. :)